# Fancybox height won't listen

Tags: jquery, fancybox, height

I am using the latest Fancybox v2.0.6 code but I am having a problem I just can't seem to solve.

This is my code:

```
$("a.postlink").fancybox({

    'width'             :   860,
    'height'        :   600,
    'autoScale'     :   false,
    'autoDimensions'        :   false,
    'type'          :   'iframe'
});
```

Everything seems to work fine, apart from the height which keeps being set to auto. If I check with Firebug I see that height is being set back to "auto".

```
<div class="fancybox-wrap fancybox-desktop fancybox-type-iframe fancybox-opened" style="width: 890px; height: auto; display: block; position: absolute; top: 1111px; left: 312px; opacity: 1;">
<div class="fancybox-skin" style="padding: 15px;">
<div class="fancybox-outer">
<div class="fancybox-inner" style="width: 860px; height: 200px; overflow: auto;">
<iframe scrolling="auto" frameborder="0" hspace="0" name="fancybox-frame1338509511183" class="fancybox-iframe" src="http://localhost:8888/quepasa/?edition=112802"></iframe></div>
<a class="fancybox-nav fancybox-prev" title="Previous"><span></span></a>
<a class="fancybox-nav fancybox-next" title="Next"><span></span></a></div>
<div class="fancybox-item fancybox-close" title="Close"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
'autoScale'     :   false
```

That is `'autoSize' : false` in fancybox version: 2.0.6